# Binding Value in Setter for TabItem is Not Working

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm-light

What I tried is

```
                <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"  Value="{Binding Active }"/>
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

> When I give `Value=false` , Its Working . 
>   
>   Tried a bunch of other stuffs , nothing helped. 
>   
>   **Thanks**

**Edit**
Below is my `ItemTemplate` and working as expected, means No binding errors.

```
 <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Display}"></TextBlock>                 
            </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: So, if it works without `Binding` `<Setter Property="IsEnabled"  Value="False"/>` the problem is probably in your viewmodel. Could share the viewmodel with us?

Comment: Look at binding errors.

Answer (score 0):

I Found My mistake,

Missed `{get;set}` in

```
public bool Active { get; set; }
```